# Сумма чисел на пути к максимальному числу в деревьях

Tags: c++, дерево

Требуется реализовать функцию которая определить сумму цифр в значениях тех узлов, которые лежат на пути от корня до максимального элемента.
Я сам пытался, но все заканчивается крахом:

```
template <class T> class TNode {
public:
   T Key; //Значение узла
   TNode* Left; //Левый потомок
   TNode* Right; //Правый потомок
   size_t count; //Счетчик числа вхождений
   int height; //Высота узла
   TNode() : Left(nullptr), Right(nullptr) {}
   TNode(T key) : Key(key), Left(nullptr), Right(nullptr), count(1), height(0) {}
   TNode(T key, TNode* lptr, TNode* rptr) :Key(key), Left(lptr), Right(rptr), count(1), height(0) {}
};
template <class T> struct SearchResult {
   T _maxValue;
   T _sum;
public:
   SearchResult() :_sum(NULL), _maxValue(NULL) {}
   TNode<T> getMaxValue() const { return _maxValue; }
   void setMaxValue(int value) { _maxValue = value; }
   void setSum(int value) { _sum = value; }
   TNode<T> getSum() const { return _sum; }
};
template <class T> class BinSTree {
protected:
   TNode<T>* root; //Указатель на корневой узел
   TNode<T>* current; //Указатель на текущий узел
   size_t size; //Число узлов в дереве
public:
void findsum(ostream& stream, const TNode<T>* node, T previousSum, SearchResult& result)
   {
       T sum = previousSum + node.data;
       if (node.data > result.getMaxValue()) {
           result.setMaxValue(node.data);
           result.setSum(sum);
       }
       if (node.Left != NULL) findsum(node.Left, sum, result);
       if (node.Right != NULL) findsum(node.Right, sum, result);
       stream << "Сумма всех чисел на пути" << sum << endl;
       stream << "Максимальное число: " << result.getMaxValue();
   }
};

//Main:
BinSTree<double>* t_tree; //Указатель на объект "Дерево"
   t_tree = new BinSTree<double>();//Инициализация на объекта "Дерево"
SearchResult<double> res ; // Значение текущей суммы 
   t_tree->findsum(cout, t_tree->getRoot(),0, res);
           cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы не выполнить задачу поэтапно?
Первым обходом находим максимум.
При втором обходе, как только находим его снова - возвращаемся до корня.

Comment: Наверное вместо второго обхода лучше выполнить целенаправленный поиск по ключу, соответствующему найденному при первом обходе максимуму (т.е. поиск максимума должен вернуть указатель на TNode)

Comment: @avp Не факт, что у автора упорядоченное дерево - в этом случае вообще достаточно было бы сразу идти по правым веткам

Comment: Судя по его коду, это двоичное дерево, предположительно упорядоченное по `Key`, а сумма собирается из `data` (в определении `class TNode` это поле отсутствует)